# Child div expand to remainder of parent

Tags: css, html

I have a div containing two divs stacked.

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    padding:4px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 4px solid #999;
}
.box1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    border: 4px solid #f00;
}
.box2 {
    border: 4px solid #00f;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div class='container'>
    <div class='box1'></div>
    <div class='box2'>
        <div style='height:400px;width:10px;background-color:#000;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Don't want DIV2 to expand past the parent div regardless of how much space DIV1 takes (as it expands with certain selections), and I want DIV2 to scroll. I thought 100% height would do it, but it expands it to the same VALUE of the parent div which is expected behavior. Tables seem to be able to do this, but I don't want to use tables.

Here is an example (In the example, the blue div should stop at the bottom of the grey div) :

http://jsfiddle.net/gateshosting/uJ7Ns/

Answer (score 2):

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ7Ns/3/)

Set height of box equal to height available minus height taken by borders minus height taken by margins

```
 box2 {
    border: 4px solid #00f;
    height: 134px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, except the main box can be resized based on browser height (Not sure if I mentioned that correctly in original post).

Comment: In that case You can set height of box when you are setting height of main box(n window resize). calculate heigh to be decreased from height of box2 use that every time you set height of box2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this with pure CSS.

You could use Javascript/jQuery though:

```
$(function(){
    //this is triggered by resizing the window
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        $(".box2").height($(".container").height() - $(".box1").height());
    }).trigger("resize"); //this initializes the height
});
```

You'd have to modify your css:

```
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%
}

.container{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    background: silver;
}

.box1{
    background: pink;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.box2{
    background: lightBlue;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

You don't want padding on the container elements (.container, .box1, .box2) because that will throw off the height by the amount you're padding.  If you want to have padding in the container elements, you should add a div inside your content with padding so your height and width is not thrown off:

CSS:

```
.pad {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='box2'>
    <div class="pad">
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
        asdf<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Try resizing the window here: http://jsfiddle.net/THWMp/3/

Comment: This works well. I was trying to get away from JQuery, only because box1 can change size, based on a selection in box1. When it changes size, I would have to trigger the resize. Box1 contains two plugins I built that change based on selections. It's a notes/activity system. Works well, except for this scrolling!!! ;)

Comment: So if you removed the height and changed the content of box1, you could trigger the window resize.  If you have it in a plugin, you could put `$(window).trigger("resize")` in a callback, like `optionSelected()` or something. http://jsfiddle.net/THWMp/4/